# browserify and class javascript prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, easeljs, browserify

So I am using browserify to manage modules for a project I am working on.

Each file contains something along the lines of this:

```
module.exports = function(){
  // class constructor
}
```

Then in my main.js file I create new objects of these like this:

```
var Foo = require('./foo.js');
var foo = new Foo();
```

The thing is, I don't know how I would use prototype inheritance in this setup.
Normally if I wanted class Foo to inherit from class Bar I would do something like this:

```
Foo.prototype = new Bar();
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;

Foo = function(){
    Bar.call(this)
}
```

How would I do something along those lines but with browserify?
I thought I would do it by replacing all the Foos with module.export, but I'm trying to inherit something from easeljs and It's just not working. It's saying that 'this' isn't defined in the initializer of a container.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With browserify, I'd recommend using the [inherits](https://www.npmjs.org/package/inherits) module.

It avoids creating a `Bar` instance to set the prototype, does the `constructor` assignment and also provides super class access.

Your use case would look like this:

```
var inherits = require('inherits');
var Bar = require('./bar');

function Foo() {
  Bar.call(this);
}

inherits(Foo, Bar);

Foo.prototype.myThing = function () { ... };

module.exports = Foo;
```

Answer (score 5):

It should look more like this, I think:

```
var Bar = require('./bar');

function Foo(){
    //...
}

Foo.prototype = new Bar();
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;

module.exports = Foo;
```

Note that you don't need to call `Bar` again in `Foo` since it's already been called once.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've marked the other one as right for the information about the require module but this works perfectly.

Comment: Actually you need to change your example:

wrong:
Foo.prototype = new Bar();


correct:
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype);